# python exit loop at any time with a key press

Tags: python, loops

Here is the current way I stop the loop:

```
# python 3.7

import keyboard

while True:
    while keyboard.is_pressed('s') == True:
        while keyboard.is_pressed('p') == False:
```

However the problem is that it only stops the loop at the end, which can take a long time. How should I make it so that I can exit the loop at any time with a key press?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it only stops the loop at the end"? Do you have a lengthy loop body that takes time to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have multiple breaks or `goto`. So you have two options: use boolean flags to check if you need to break out of the outer loop, or use the `else` case of a `while` loop, which executes if the loop didn't break.

To use flags:

```
exit_required = False;
while not exit_required:
  while not exit_required and keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
    while not exit_required and not keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
      exit_required = True;
```

To use the `else` case:

```
while True:
  while keyboard.is_pressed('s') == True:
    while keyboard.is_pressed('p') == False:
      break;
    else:
      continue; # executes if the loop didn't break
    break;      # if the inner loop executed break, this one breaks too
  else:
    continue;   # same thing here
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
import keyboard
import time

a = False

def exitLoop():
    global a
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print("Exiting loop")
            a = True
            break 

t = threading.Thread(target=exitLoop)
t.start()

while a == False:
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(1)
```

that should take care of it and it is more clear

basically exitLoop runs in background

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `try`-block and catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception:

```py
import time

def some_long_run_task():
    print("Start")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Done")


while True:
    try:
        some_long_run_task()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Break out of the loop!")
        break
```

Then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break the loop in the middle.